# Qual a melhor maneira de enviar email com HTML em Django?

Tags: django, envio-de-email

Sou iniciante em Python e Django e no projeto que estou fazendo para estudo, eu envio um e-mail, que tem um template HTML. Consegui enviar um e-mail com HTML utilizando o `EmailMessage`:

```python
msg = EmailMessage(subject, template.render(variables), sender, recipients)
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

Gostaria de saber se essa é a meneira recomendada e/ou se existe alguma maneira mais fácil e/ou melhor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu gosto de utilizar o EmailMultiAlternatives para o caso de envios com alternativas de txt e html. Caso deseje utilizar ele uma forma de fazê-lo é:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

message_html = render_to_string('seutemplate.html', dict_contexto)
message_txt = render_to_string('seutemplate.txt', dict_contexto)

subject = u"Um assunto"
from_email = u'email@remetente.com'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message_txt, from_email,        
                             ['email@destinatario1.com'])
msg = msg.attach_alternative(message, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Ou se deseja algo mais simples, pode optar pela função padrão do django, a [send_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail). Exemplo:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
          ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Lembrando que para que o envio funcione, você precisará configurar um backend de envio, com a variável EMAIL_BACKEND do settings. Para testar local você poderá usar o console backend, onde a mensagem, após o envio, aparecerá no shell. Para usar o console backend atribua o seguinte valor para o EMAIL_BACKEND:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```